# Yii Criteria->with without relation or without 'on'

Tags: join, yii, criteria, cgridview, cactivedataprovider

How to create `criteria->with()` witout "on" or without "default relation"
in query?

```
select *
from status kk 
inner join user tt 
left join userstatus ii on kk.status_id = ii.status_id 
    and ii.user_id = tt.user_id
```

I want use it for `CGridView` search in YII for `dataProvider`.

Or is there any other way that could diapakai to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

CDbCriteria::with requires you to have relations defined. If you want to manually join tables, the class also allows you to do that with the join property

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#join-detail

Answer (score 0):

You can define [relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) in your model, than use it in your search method.
For example

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
        );
    }
```

and in search method:

```
public function search() {        
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with = array('user');
        ......
}
```